# The plotting function in R igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I use igraph R to visualize chemical compounds. In this approach, nodes correspond to atoms and edges correspond to bonds between atoms. Such represented chemical molecule is known as a molecular graph or H-depleted graphs. For instance, to represent 2-methylbutane, 2mb for short, (simple organic molecule whose carbon skeleton consists of five atoms) I use the following R code:

```
molecular.graph.2mb = graph.formula(1-2,2-3,3-4,2-5)
```

To visualize this molecular graph I use as a layout the following matrix m:

```
m = matrix(c(1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,2,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE).
```

This matrix contains coordinates of vertices of my graph. Then I plot this graph:

```
plot(molecular.graph.2mb, layout=m).
```

I obtain the graph where the geometrical distance between the vertices 2 and 5 is larger than between v1 and v2, v2 and v3 as well as v3 and v4.

My question is: How to force igraph R to plot the graph where all geometrical distances will be equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main trick to doing this is to set the parameter `rescale=FALSE` and adjust the `xlim`. Doing that alone made the nodes very small so I needed to adjust the node size as well. I think this is what you are looking for.

```
library(igraph)

## Your graph
molecular.graph.2mb = graph.formula(1-2,2-3,3-4,2-5)
m = matrix(c(1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,2,1), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE)

## Modified plot
plot(molecular.graph.2mb, layout=m, rescale=FALSE,
    vertex.size=30, xlim=c(0.5,4.5))
```

[image: Evenly spaced]

Comment: Thanks for aswer. This is what I was looking for. How to adjust the xlim parameter ? By trial and error method, I think. Piotr Wilczek.

Comment: There shouldn't need to be much trial and error. Because I used `rescale=FALSE` it is using the x-coordinates that you set up in `m` Those run from 1 to 4 and you need a little bit of a border, so 0.5-4.5 came easy.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Piotr Wilczek